# Serializing objects in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When a user uploads something via my app, I create an ASIFormDataRequest object to make the POST.

When the user is offline, I would like to write a ASIFormDataRequest object to file and send it later.

Is there a built in way to serialize an object like this in Objective C, or do I have to write something from scratch?

Comment: I would say that trying to serialize the request object isn't the right solution to this problem. I would store the data contained in the request instead, and rebuild the request and send it when online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep!  There's a really great thing called the `NSCoding` protocol.  A writeup on how to implement and use it is available on our local CocoaHeads site:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding  In a nutshell, you implement two methods to define what you want to save and how to restore it, and then it's a one-liner to actually archive your object.

Comment: Yep the link is dead, an actual code example would be very appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else still coming here and looking for what Cocoaheads originally had up, here is an archived copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20130330051451/cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding

Answer (score 2):

> In the Objective-C programming
>   language, serialization (more commonly
>   known as archiving) is achieved by
>   overriding the write: and read:
>   methods in the Object root class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Objective-C

There's a code example there too :-)

Comment: huh, I've *never* heard of doing it that way

Comment: interesting.. maybe the Wikipedia page needs updating?

Comment: I actually saw this and originally thought all objects have a built in write method, but then I realized I had to write one if I wanted to do it this way.